# Clear difference between $(x≠y)∧P(x)$ and $(x≠y)→P(x)$ in logic

Tags: logic

> Let $M(x,y)$ be “$x$ has sent $y$ an e-mail message” and $T(x,y)$ be “$x$ has telephoned $y$,” where the domain consists of all students in your class.
>
> > Every student in the class has either received an email message or received a telephone call from another student in the class.
>
> Use quantiﬁers to express each of these statements.

I come out with $∀x∃y((x≠y)→(M(y,x)∨T(y,x)))$. However, the answer given is $∀x∃y((x≠y)∧(M(y,x)∨T(y,x))$. Can anyone please explain the difference between them? Thank you.

Comment: Your solution means "every student $x$ has another student $y$ such that *if $x$ and $y$ are different* then either $M(x,y)$ or $T(x,y)$. We cannot conclude $M(x,y)$ or $T(x,y)$ unless $x$ and $y$ are different.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get your last sentence. Can you further explain it? Thank you.

Comment: Your conditional does mean, $M(x,y)$ or $T(x,y)$ only when $x\neq y$. We do not know anything when $x=y$.

Comment: Hint: $A\to B ~~\equiv ~~\neg (A \land \neg B)$

Comment: Ya. That's what the question wants. It doesn't mention about the situation of M/T when x=y.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is always true, regardless of what has been mailed or telephoned, because for all $x$ there is a $y$ such that $x = y$, which makes the whole implication true.

The bracketed statement in the given answer *requires* that $x\neq y$ in order to be true. Yours does not, but only states what we require *in the case* where $x$ and $y$ are unequal.